# MariaDB and Strange Display

Tags: mariadb

I specify that I do not work with the last version of MariaDB but I do not have the hand on the server to make an update.
So I'm working with version 10.0.36.

I recreated a simple table of which here is the structure and the contents to explain my problem.
[image]

My problem is on rendering an SQL query. If I run this query :

```
select VIS.idVisite as 'key',if(VIS.weightVisite is not NULL,VIS.weightVisite,'') as 'weight' 
from visite as VIS 
inner join client as CLI on VIS.idClientVisite=CLI.idClient 
where VIS.idVisite in (1,2,3,4) 
order by VIS.idVisite
```

I get this:
[image]

The decimals of digits greater than or equal to 100 are not displayed.

If I modify the query like this:

```
select VIS.idVisite as 'key',VIS.weightVisite as 'weight' 
from visite as VIS 
inner join client as CLI on VIS.idClientVisite=CLI.idClient 
where VIS.idVisite in (1,2,3,4) 
order by VIS.idVisite;
```

I get this :
[image]

Decimals are displayed correctly

If I modify the query like this:

```
select VIS.idVisite as 'key',if(VIS.weightVisite is not NULL,VIS.weightVisite,'') as 'weight' 
from visite as VIS 
where VIS.idVisite in (1,2,3,4)
```

I get this:
[image]

Decimals are displayed correctly

So...?
I am lost. Why when I combine the "IF" condition with the "INNER JOIN" I don't have the right decimals...?
While the "IF" alone works fine.
While the "INNER JOIN" alone works well.

If someone has an idea.

And the structure of client table is this :
[image]

Comment: Did you check whether this is a database problem, or a displaying problem? Maybe phpMyAdmin modifies the numbers?

Comment: @NicoHaase I discover this problem when I want to extract datas after execute query in my PHP Script. And I test after the queries on phpMyAdmin.

Comment: weightVisite FLOAT(4,1) ???? You also have  a client table ? Can you please share it also?

Comment: The float of 4.1 would be the problem... ? But it does not pose any problem for the secondand third request. Yes I have the client table. I will edit my question to show this table

Comment: Please keep in mind to add as most information as possible  **in text form** to your question. Something like the table structure is shared best as `CREATE TABLE`

Comment: Can you reproduce it with another SQL client? I don't see any reason why casting a float to string can produce a trailing decimal point. It totally looks like a bug in the display code.

Comment: It seems that problem is with data type! Change FLOAT(4,1) with DECIMAL(4,1) and test again please. On my terminal, Problem is solved!

Comment: Any good reason you're converting the weight to char? That's what is happening for `if(VIS.weightVisite is not NULL,VIS.weightVisite,'')`. If you change to `if(VIS.weightVisite is not NULL,VIS.weightVisite,0)` it works as expected

Comment: @OzanSen
I hadn't tested with decimal(4,1) and you're right it works fine. But I had tested with float(5,1) and it worked too.
But why is my query not working with `IF` and `INNER JOIN` and float(4,1)...?
For other queries the display is fine. And without intervening on the database.

Comment: @Vinicius I'm converting because I don't want to display anything. And that's a good idea, but why does a query with only "IF" work...? while I convert to char...?

Comment: And I also found the solution to put `if(VIS.weightVisite is not NULL,round(VIS.weightVisite,1),'') as 'weight'`.
And it works. But my question is why one query works and the other doesn't. It's amazing, isn't it?

Comment: Any option that is not explicitly casting may work now but it is not guaranteed to always work (eg., may fail when you upgrade the server). Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your query is that you are letting the database do an implicit type conversion from float to string using this statement:

```
if(VIS.weightVisite is not NULL,VIS.weightVisite,'')
```

This is not a good practice (from [MariaDB docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/type-conversion/)):

> Implicit type conversion takes place when MariaDB is using operands or
> different types, in order to make the operands compatible.
>
> It is best practice not to rely upon implicit conversion; rather use
> CAST to explicitly convert types.

For some unknown reason the DB converts this sometimes to char(4) and sometimes to (probably) char(5).

You can explicitly cast it, like:

```
if(VIS.weightVisite is not NULL,cast(VIS.weightVisite as char(5)),'')
```

or

```
cast(if(VIS.weightVisite is not NULL,VIS.weightVisite,'') as char(5))
```

And it will always show the correct result. But if casting to char was not your intention, you can avoid it using the correct type:

```
if(VIS.weightVisite is not NULL,VIS.weightVisite,0)
```

Comment: One comment though, if you are converting a decimal type to string at the DB level, you must be sure weather it is always using the intended decimal character.

Comment: I agree with you, my way of doing things was not optimal. I will use the `CAST`.
Thanks again for your help. Although I still don't understand why some queries work and not others. Just by adding an `INNER JOIN` for example.
But thanks again for your solution.

Comment: The solution you proposed works well on display but in principle I have questions.
The `CAST` must be there to transform the `float` into a character string if we want to be logical.
Thus the "weight" alias contains either a character string with the `float`, or an empty character string.
Either the query : `select VIS.idVisite as 'key',if(VIS.weightVisite is not NULL,cast(VIS.weightVisite as char(5)),'') as 'weight' 
from visite as VIS 
inner join client as CLI on VIS.idClientVisite=CLI.idClient 
where VIS.idVisite in (1,2,3,4) 
order by VIS.idVisite`

Comment: Putting the cast anywhere works because you give the DB a hint to the type you want to the output but your query is obviously more logical. I'll update the answer.